# new location of email-ext templates under Jenkins home

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I am can use the default html template from email-ext plugin, but I cannot locate the template file under the plugin directory. Where can I edit this default html.jelly template? In earlier versions of Jenkins these used to be located under the plugins/email-ext directory in Jenkins home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your template in \Jenkins\email-templates\YOUR_TEMPLATE.jelly.
If there is no email-templates folder, just create it.

Comment: Lets say I've created a template named `mytemplate.jelly` now how would I use this template for my email-body, do I need to write something in `Default Pre-send Script` to use my customized template. I mean I am not clear how to use the template.... could you please guide me.

Comment: you need to give this jelly file to email-ext plugin. Add "Editable email-notification" in postbuild actions. Then add following to 'Default content':   ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="mytemplate"}

Comment: I found your answer suffering this error: "Jelly file [html] was not found in $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates" after a Jenkins upgrade. I copied https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/html.jelly into a new folder /var/lib/jenkins/email-templates and it works again. Thanks for your hint. Could you add a link to the documentation of this folder?